Why is heat flux said to be per unit area?
Heat flux is defined to be the flow of energy per unit area per unit time. But I do not understand where the "per unit area" comes from.
In Fourier's law, heat flux is modeled to be
$$
\phi=-k\nabla T
$$
Isn't the gradient of a function a vector field? Therefore $\phi$ is a function of position, that is it: it evaluates to the vector of heat flux at a specific point, and not the total heat flux in a unit area around that point? In other words, shouldn't the function evaluate to a vector which encodes the direction of heat flux where it's magnitude is equal to the watts being transferred across a point and not some area? Why in reality the unit is $\frac{W}{m^2}$? What fundamentals am I missing?

Well, if you want the total heat transferred you would integrate over the area to get it. The useful units come out naturally.

The current desnsity is anoter quantity of the "flux" type and is a vector defined per unit area. It is related to the elctric field which is well, a field, a function of position.

It’s the watts per area as the area gets vanishing small.

The author used "flux", where other authors might have used "flux density". Typically flux density is the flux per area.

I think this misunderstanding happens because in Physics we usually have different starting points; it all depends what you consider the "fundamental quantity".
For example, let's talk about flux. In vector calculus, if we have a vector field $\vec A$, we define it flux through a surface $S$ as
$$
\Phi_A(S) = \int_S \vec A \cdot d\vec\sigma.
$$
In physics, if we consider $\vec A$ as a fundamental physical quantity measured in some unity, let's say an unit Euler, the unity of flux will be Euler$\cdot m^2$ (assuming meters squared as unity of area). But sometimes, the flux is considered a fundamental physical quantity that deserves more attention. When it happens, usually the flux $\Phi_A$ receives a unity, let's say Lagrange, and the quantity $\vec A$ is now measured as Lagrange$/m^2$. It happens that in this case, to emphasize that the flux plays the main role, the quantity $\vec A$ is called flux density. In electromagnetism, for example, sometimes the field $\vec B$ is called magnetic flux density, emphasizing the role of it flux in physics phenomena.
In your question, we know by experience that heat transfer behaves like a flux. If we increase the area, it increases heat transfer for example. And it is measured in $W$. So this is a case where the flux is the fundamental quantify. We then define a density as a vector field $\vec q$ such that
$$
Q = \int_S \vec q\cdot d\vec \sigma.
$$
The idea then is to study such Vector Field.

Am I understanding correctly the fact that any vector field evaluates to is its own flux density?

Yes. Remember about magnetic field = magnetic density flux.

That seems needlessly complicated (although it likely has a utility that I'm not aware of), but it does resolve all my doubts. Thank you!
